# How to reload a web-page each minute automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm a newbie at chrome developer tools.
I want a simple thing:

How to reload a some webpage (for instance, pinterest or twitter page) each minute, using some script in chrome developer console?

Comment: @evolutionxbox — Not a duplicate of that. That is about editing the page, not using the developer tools on a page that you can't edit.

Comment: @Quentin why not? Is the answer still not the same? (Except saving the script in a "snippet")

Comment: @evolutionxbox — What's a snippet? Is that a Chrome Developer Tools feature?

Comment: @Quentin alright smarty pants ;) --- yes snippets is a feature in chrome dev tools under the sources tab.

Comment: @evolutionxbox — Never heard of it before. Looks like it is a way to save scripts so you can access them easily later. I can't see any obvious bit of UI that would make the script run whenever I loaded a page though. How do you do that?

Comment: I think the answer for this is: "you can't" since Chrome does not allow executing arbitrary scripts on load. You can use a plugin like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc?hl=en) though.

Comment: @Quentin no it doesn't let you do that. The OP would have to create an extension which would still exist once the page has reloaded.

Comment: I've made a browser plugin (from shit and bricks). 

Thank all of you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function you can use to refresh any page.

Copy-paste this function first -

```
function refresh(secs) {
  document.documentElement.innerHTML = '<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden"><iframe frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%" id="p" src="' + window.location.href + '"></iframe></body>'
  setInterval(() => document.getElementById('p').src = document.getElementById('p').src, secs * 1000)
}
```

Then use it like so -

```
refresh(10) // refresh every 10sec
```

You can pass any other number to customize the refresh interval in seconds.

What this basically does, is to put the current page in an iframe and then periodically refreshing it.

Comment: Why the downvote? This works for OPs scenario. Appreciate any feedback and alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the setTimeout function or metaTag in the html page which you are working on.
I like using meta tag it's neat and easy.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2";>
```

Here is the link for more information about it.
    https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Comment: If you add this dynamically, this won't work after the page has reloaded. OP is asking for a solution that works for any web page.